# Asus router - Longtime to recognize ethernet connection

Tags: router, ethernet, asus, fios

I just got a new Asus RT-AX86U router. Setup was fast, WiFi range is excellent, speed is good, but ...

When a computer connected via Ethernet wakes up from sleep it takes up to 60 seconds for the connection to start working. The same issue happens if I physically unplug the Ethernet cable and plug it back in (which is a lot quicker to experiment with than putting the computer to sleep). I did a bunch of debugging and here is what I found:

- The problem did not exist with my previous router (FIOS G3100)
- Router has latest stock firmware
- I also tried with Merlin and saw the same issue
- Tests were done with short Cat 5e cables
  The problem: Unplug the wire, plug it back in (or put computer to
  sleep) and it takes 40-60 seconds for the connection to recover
- Issue happens on different Computers connected to the router via Ethernet.
- Issue happens regardless of which LAN port on the router I connect
  to
- If I connect the computer to the router through a hub then:

  - Disconnecting the hub-computer cable and plug it back in --- the
    connection is up and running within 3 or 4 seconds as expected
  - Disconnecting the hub-router cable and plug it back in --- The
    computer (Windows really) thinks everything is connected, but the
    actual connection takes 40-60 seconds to come back up

** ***Update*** **

It turns out the problem only happens when a very specific device is connected to one of the router's other ports.  I have an old FIOS Actiontec router configured as a bridge in order to provide MoCA  to the FIOS TV Box.   I have set up the Actiontec router as a bridge: turned off WiFi, turned off its DHCP server, turned off its broadband connection, bridged the LAN ports to the coax port.  The Actiontec router is working fine as bridge -- the TV box is able to obtain IP address from my main Asus router and is able to connect to the internet.

HOWEVER - Whenever the Actiontec router is on the network with the Asus router, other computers connected to the Asus router take 40-60 seconds to establish a connection when waking up from sleep or when the cable is first plugged in.

I have tried setting  up the Actiontec router to obtain an IP from the main Asus router (assigned, not random) as well as setting up the Actiontec router to use a static IP.  Didn't make a difference.   There also isn't a difference regardless of whether anything else(e.g. the TV box) is connected to the Actiontec.  I have also tried connecting the Actiontec via a switch as opposed to directly with the Asus, that also didn't make a difference.

Clearly the Actiontec is causing some sort of headache for the Asus when other devices are first connecting.  It doesn't seem to impact performance in any other way, however.

I welcome any ideas on what could cause the Actiontec to mess around with other ports on the Asus router.

Thanks!

Comment: As this happens with different computers, different Ethernet cables and different ports on the router I would contact Asus support as this is not a normal behavior.

Comment: Therein lies the rub.  I bought the router at Best Buy.  Asus outsources all their tech support to Geek Squad when an item is purchased at BG.  I don't have high hopes besides returning router.